# How to upload multiple files to FTP Server without blocking in C#?

Tags: c#

How to upload multiple files to FTP Server without blocking  in C# ?
I dont want to block other Any code snippet is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx?ppud=4).

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FtpUpload, "path/to/file1.txt");
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FtpUpload, "path/to/file2.txt");
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(FtpUpload, "path/to/file3.txt");

...

private static void FtpUpload(object state) {
    var filePath = (string)state;
    ... upload here ...
}
```

Comment: I understood your code looks like what i want exactly.Can you tell me in Upload logic how i can give multiple files to upload ? Using FTPWebRequest I have to Upload ? Any code snippet ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

Comment: the link you provided is ok sam but how to upload multiple files with thread pool.How do that ?

Comment: @Swapnil Gupta, take the example from the link of how to upload, and combine it with the above example on how to use `ThreadPool`.  If you still have problems, post a new question with the minimum amount of your code needed to reproduce the problem and ask for further assistance.